# How can I add a new item to system.webServer/handlers programmatically in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, httphandler

This is a sample part from web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Can I add a new handler it programmatically when web application starts (maybe somewhere in global.asax?).

I want to add something like that:

```
<add name="AbpDynamicServiceProxyhandler" path="api/serviceproxies/*.js" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

But I want to add it when application starting since it's needed for a library I am developing and I dont want to force user to add this line manually.

NOTE: I dont mean to open web.config and add the line programmatically. I want to make same effect with code on startup without modifying web.config of the application.

Comment: It is not a module where you after: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.registermodule.aspx ?

Comment: @rene, I did not understand what did you mean? Isn't it possible? Because if I add this line to web.config, it works as i expected.

Comment: I'm always lost where a handler goes and where a module goes. That link points to a method that is available to Register a Module which seems new in .net 4.5. There is no RegisterHandler, AFAIK. The closest you can get I guess is described [here](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/handlers) which is already rejected as an option by you.

Comment: @rene think that I registered a module, what can I do with it? Can I handle path "api/serviceproxies/*.js"? I think IIS handles .js and it does not allow ASP.NET to handle the request unless we define the section in web.config. So, How I can handle this .js request and create the js dynamically?

Comment: which version of .Net / asp.net are you? This not MVC?

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4.

Comment: In that case I would research [Routes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.ASPX). I assume a route for api/serviceproxies/ to a specific controller is possible and I expect easier.

Comment: I already added it to routes: config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "AbpDynamicWebApiProxy",
                routeTemplate: "api/serviceproxies/{name}.js",
                defaults: new { controller = "ServiceProxies", action = "Get" }
                ); but IIS does not sends request unless I add the handler line to web.config.

Comment: And if you get rid of the .js at the end?

Comment: I want to work it with ".js" that is the problem. If I work without extension, existing handlers handle it and works. The reason I want to handle it with .js is that I'm using require.js and it automatically adds .js to javascript modules and I don't want to change it's default behaviour since it causes another problem.

Comment: Ok, understood. Then you're back to the HttpHandler which can't be inserted at runtime AFAIK. The handler sits closer to iis then to asp.net pipeline. Maybe add the AP.NET MVC tag to your question to attract some clever minds from that camp...

Answer (score -2):

Does this help you:

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/handlers

It contains  programmatic and command line examples

Comment: Please note that the question is about *adding handlers on-the-fly in memory*, for example in application start. Your examples are about registering them once through the web administration API, that is a different thing.